# Live auction bidding system

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create live auction bidding system where if a bid is placed by user x then another higher bid is placed by user y, it will automatically and immediately update the current highest bidder for user x. 
I've been advised that javascript is the best for such a system however it would have security issues. I would love to code this in PHP but as far as I know, this is not possible.

What sort of a security issue am I looking at here?
Anyone can advise on how to go about codding this?

Comment: You will face security issues to matter what. Furthermore you aren't able to do an auction system with client-side javascript only. You will need PHP or another server-side language not to mention a database.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer getting as much logic away from the user. Let's say your have a database table which holds the bids of an auction. When a logged in user clicks the bid button, JavaScript could send a request to your server using AJAX. Use a nonce to verify that the request comes from your site and the user sessions to identify which user is making the bid. You than add the bid to the auction table.

You'll also need JavaScript to constantly check with your server whether the most recent bid has changed. You can use exactly the structure as above, but for selecting data instead of inserting data. How often you want the check to occur depends on the context but since this is an auction, you'll probably need to check it at least once a second.

If you implement a safe user login system with reasonable passwords and nonces to make sure the requests come from your site, you've come a long way.